# Не работает метод messages.send() в vk_api Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Я не понимаю, почему не работает метод `messages.get()`. Обьясню: в данном кусочке кода:

```
if text.lower() == "D":
    vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
    print (user_id)
elif text.lower() == "F":
    vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
    print (user_id)
elif text.lower() == "G":
    vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
    print (user_id)
elif text.lower() == "H":
    vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
    print (user_id)
```

Я указал, что когда пользователь отвечает D или F или G или H, то бот должен ответить пользователю, что ответ был передан администратору, но этого не происходит: ничего не отсылается

[image: Проблема]

Логи прилагаю.

[Логи](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cv2nal0xaoZ7WZsiGhv9fVxj9fjGQoRC/view?usp=sharing)

Вот весь мой код

```
import vk_api # pip install vk_api
import random
import datetime #pip install datetime
import time
import logging
from playsound import playsound #pip install playsound

# Логирование
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG, filename='log.txt')

token = "мой токен" # токен в переменной

print ("Bot made by resh")
logging.warning('Debug started! Waiting for messages...')

#main part
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = token) # Подключение токена 
vk._auth_token()

while True:
    messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset":0,"count":20,"filter":"unanswered"}) # Так сказать читаем все диалоги, даем боту доступ
    #account = vk.method("account.ban", {"owner_id":})  ЗАГОТОВКА НА БУДУЩЕЕ (ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ ЗАБАНИТЬ ЧЕЛОВЕКА)
    uploader = vk_api.upload.VkUpload(vk) # Подключение загрузчика фотографий
    if messages['count'] >= 1:
        text = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['text']
        user_id = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['from_id']
        users_names = vk.method("users.get", {"user_ids":"user_id", "name_case":"nom"})
        #vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Напиши 'start', чтобы я помог тебе", "random_id":random.randint(1,1000)})
        if text.lower() == "start":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Привет, я твой помощник.", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
            vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Выбери то, что ты хочешь (ответ напиши цифрой): ", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
            vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"1)Конфиг\n 2)Реселл\n 3)Мне нужна помощь администратора", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
        if text.lower() == "1":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Выбери, на какой чит ты хочешь получить конфиг (ответ напиши буквой):\n D)Nixware.cc beta\n F)nemesis.technology crack\n G)onetap.com V3 crack\n H)goodtap.pw", "random_id":random.randint(1,1000)})
            if text.lower() == "D":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
                print (user_id)
            elif text.lower() == "F":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
                print (user_id)
            elif text.lower() == "G":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
                print (user_id)
            elif text.lower() == "H":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
                print (user_id)
        elif text.lower() == "2":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Реселл какого чита ты хочешь? (ответ цифрой)\n a)onetap.com\n b)aimware.net\n c)Свой вариант ответа", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
            if text.lower() == "a":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
            elif text.lower() == "b":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
            elif text.lower() == "c":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
        elif text.lower() == "3":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"user_id":user_id, "message":"Спасибо! Ответ передан администратору, ожидайте", "random_id":random.randint(1,10000000)})
            logging.critical (users_names, 'NEED FOR YOUR HELP!!!')
            int_for_logs = "users_names"
            playsound('bruh.wav')
```

Comment: `text.lower()` никогда не равно `"D"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if text.lower() == "D":
```

text.lower() меняет текст с БОЛЬШОГО на маленький. Т.е. D становиться d.

```
if text.lower() == "d":
```

И так везде поменяй.